# imshow and histogram2d: can't get them to work

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm learning Python and this is my first question here. I've read other topics related to the usage of **imshow** but didn't find anything useful. Sorry for my bad English.

I have plotted a set of points here, left graphic:

[points (left) and image (right)](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10411539/python/image.png)

Now I'd like to see an image of the density of points, so I used **imshow** and **histogram2d**, and I got the image to the right in the previous link.

The image doesn't correspond to the distribution of points. How is this possible? I've followed the instructions in the help and even changed some parameters but nothing worked :(

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

j, h, k = np.loadtxt("test.dat", usecols=(2, 4, 6), \
    unpack=True)

# límites
xmin = -0.5
xmax =  3.0
ymin = -0.5
ymax =  4.0

# colores
j_h = j - h
h_k = h - k

# no todas las estrellas son graficadas    
x1 = 0.5
y1 = 0.5
b  = 2.2
c  = y1 - b * x1

x = y = np.array([])

for xi, yi in zip(h_k, j_h):
    if xi < (yi - c) / b:
        x = np.append(x, xi)
        y = np.append(y, yi)

# gráfico
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 7))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
#ax.plot(x, y, "go")
ax.set_xlabel(r"X", fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel(r"Y", fontsize=14)
ax.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])

# imagen
rango = [[xmin, xmax], [ymin, ymax]]
binsx = int((xmax - xmin) / 0.05)
binsy = int((ymax - ymin) / 0.05)
binsxy = [binsx, binsy]

H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, range=rango, bins=binsxy)

extent = [yedges[0], yedges[-1], xedges[0], xedges[-1]]
cp = ax.imshow(H, interpolation='bilinear', extent=extent, cmap=cm.jet)
fig.colorbar(cp)

plt.show()
```

The links for the data used is here:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10411539/python/test.dat

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: specify `origin='lower'` for the imshow function

Comment: @gcalmettes: This didn't work :(

Comment: Now it worked, but setting H.transpose(). Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try different interpolation, and transpose the matrix to get it in the same axis:

```
cp = ax.imshow(H.transpose()[::-1], interpolation='nearest', extent=extent, cmap=cm.jet)
```

Comment: @skytux you are right, the axes were swapped. I just updated my answer. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: This worked fine with the matrix transposed and... ([::-1]) what is this?? But I used extent as DiggyF said before because in my case it was inverted. Thanks very much!!

Comment: [::-1] traverses the array in the inverse direction. You're welcome!

Comment: Now I understand why it worked with H.transpose() and origin='lower'. If I remove the origin parameter then I need to use [::-1]. Thanks again!! :)

Comment: Why is a transposition necessary? The docs for numpy.histogram2d label the arguments as `x, y`.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want to get? You can use pcolor (and pcolormesh) if you want to pass the x and y coordinates.

```
import urllib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f = urllib.urlopen('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10411539/python/test.dat')
j, h, k = np.loadtxt(f, usecols=(2, 4, 6), \
    unpack=True)
j, h, k
j_h = j - h
h_k = h - k
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(j_h, h_k, bins=100)
plt.pcolor(xedges, yedges, H)
```

[image: Example of pcolor using histogram2d]

For imshow you have to reverse the first dimension, because imshow uses zero-based row, column indices to the x, y. Drawing from the top down.

```
plt.imshow(H[::-1,:], extent=(0,5, 0,2.5)) # typed in extent by hand.
```

[image: imshow example]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In the first case (pcolor) you use j_h (x-axis) first and then h_k (y-axis). Is that correct?... because my plot is the opposite. Also bins must be equal in x and y directions? In the second case (imshow) the density image doesn't follow the direction of the points if you plot them together...

Comment: Imshow assumes equidistant x and y coordinates. Pcolor also works for non equidistant and non rectilinear coordinates. I thought I'd leave out some of the x,y calculation as a simpler example. The main thing is that imshow, by default, has the origin on the top. The origin=lower option, which gcalmettes suggested, is more elegant.

Comment: Indeed using origin=lower worked, but only with H.transpose() !!

Comment: I had to make the following changes to get this to work: `import urllib.request` and `f = urllib.request.urlopen(...`