# Order of arguments in numpys histogram2d

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am a bit puzzled by how axis are oriented in histogram2d. The [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) gives the following example:

```
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(y, x, bins=(xedges, yedges))
```

Note that y and x are flipped in the input arguments, but not in the output.
The result of this operation can be viewed by imshow like this, according to the doc:

```
im = plt.imshow(H, interpolation='nearest', origin='low',extent=[xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]])
```

However, the axis seem flipped in this case, as in the following example:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xdata = np.ones(10)*1
ydata = np.ones(10)*2
H,xedges,yedges = np.histogram2d(ydata,xdata)
plt.imshow(H,origin='low', extent=[xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]],interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you see, x and y axis are switched - the points generated all lie at (1,2). Of course one can flip the entries in extent= to change to axis, but that does not help, as can be seen by the following:

```
R = [[0.5,1.5],[2,3]]
H,xedges,yedges = np.histogram2d(ydata,xdata,range=R)
plt.imshow(H,origin='low', extent=[yedges[0], yedges[-1], xedges[0], xedges[-1]],interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The only version that seems to do what I want is this;

```
H,yedges,xedges = np.histogram2d(ydata,xdata)
plt.imshow(H,origin='low', extent=[xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]],interpolation='none')
plt.show()
R = [[2,3],[0.5,1.5]]
H,yedges,xedges = np.histogram2d(ydata,xdata,range=R)
plt.imshow(H,origin='low', extent=[xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]],interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

That is, I have to flip all the input arguments and output arguments, and of course the range parameters. Is that the correct way of using this routine, or am I missing something important?

Comment: I recommend to use pcolor instead of imshow if you have x and y values given: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367683/imshow-and-histogram2d-cant-get-them-to-work

Comment: Hi dnalow, thanks, I will consider that!